# sbt.ResolveException play-bootstrap-SNAPSHOT

Tags: playframework-2.0, sbt, scalac, sbteclipse, lagom

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/yannickdeturck/lagom-shop) for Eclipse. here are the errors that I have no clue what to do

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.adrianhurt#play-bootstrap_2.11;1.1-P25-B3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          com.adrianhurt:play-bootstrap_2.11:1.1-P25-B3-SNAPSHOT (D:\WorkSpace\lagom\lagom-shop\build.sbt#L51)
[warn]            +- be.yannickdeturck.lagomshop:front-end_2.11:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last front-end/*:update for the full output.
[error] (front-end/*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.adrianhurt#play-bootstrap_2.11;1.1-P25-B3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[error] Could not create Eclipse project files:
[error] Error evaluating task 'scalacOptions': error
[error] Error evaluating task 'externalDependencyClasspath': error
>
```

Answer (score 0):

so I had to change the build.sbt file as follow

```
lazy val frontEnd = project("front-end") ...
 "com.adrianhurt" %% "play-bootstrap" % "1.0-P25-B3"
```